# Spring Boot WebClient with OAuth2 and use InsecureTrustManagerFactory

Tags: spring-boot, spring-oauth2, spring-webclient

I have successfully implemented WebClient with oAuth2. Facing problem with oAuth2 when the Authentication Server (Keycloak) is having SSL (https). Though I am passing InsecureTrustManagerFactory while defining WebClient, this oAuth is called before the builder is complete as it is there in the filter, it uses default implementation of WebClient and throws certification error.

Is there a way we can configure oAuth2 client also to use InsecureTrustManagerFactory?

pom.xml part

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Bean Configuration

```
@Bean
public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
        final ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
        final ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
    logger.info("ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager Bean Method");
    ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider = ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder
            .builder().password().build();

    AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
            clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);

    authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

    authorizedClientManager.setContextAttributesMapper(oAuth2AuthorizeRequest -> Mono
            .just(Map.of(OAuth2AuthorizationContext.USERNAME_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, System.getProperty("user"),
                    OAuth2AuthorizationContext.PASSWORD_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, System.getProperty("pass"))));

    return authorizedClientManager;
}

/**
 * The Oauth2 based WebClient bean for the web service
 * 
 * @throws SSLException
 */
@Bean
public WebClient webClient(ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) throws SSLException {

    String registrationId = "bael";

    SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forClient().trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
            .build();

    SslProvider sslProvider = SslProvider.builder().sslContext(sslContext).build();

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure(sslProvider)
            .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 5000).responseTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(5000))
            .doOnConnected(conn -> conn.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                    .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));

    ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
            authorizedClientManager);
    oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId(registrationId);
    logger.info("WebClient Bean Method");
    return WebClient.builder()
            // base path of the client, this way we need to set the complete url again
            .baseUrl("BASE_URL")
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).filter(logRequest())
            .filter(oauth).filter(logResponse()).build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have to make new WebClient for OAuth2 too.
In your authorizedClientManager definition add some strings(It's better to have HttpClient bean, so you won't define it all the time)

```
SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forClient().trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
            .build();
SslProvider sslProvider = SslProvider.builder().sslContext(sslContext).build();
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure(sslProvider)
            .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 5000).responseTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(5000))
            .doOnConnected(conn -> conn.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                    .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                .build();
WebClientReactiveClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient clientCredentialsTokenResponseClient =
                new WebClientReactiveClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient();
        clientCredentialsTokenResponseClient.setWebClient(webClient);
```

and add in your authorizedClientProvider ->

```
ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider = ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder
            .builder().password(builder -> builder.accessTokenResponseClient(clientCredentialsTokenResponseClient)).build();
```